# Azure DevOps versioning pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, branching-and-merging

The following pipeline is used for tagging versions:

```
trigger:
  - main

pool: Default

variables:
  version.MajorMinor: '1.0' 
  version.HotFix: '0.0.1'
  version.Revision: $[counter(variables['version.MajorMinor'], 0)]
  version.HotfixInc: $[counter(variables['version.HotFix'])]
  stableVersionNumber: '$(version.MajorMinor).$(version.Revision)'
  minorVersionNumber: 
  hotFixVersionNumber: 
  versionNumber: 
  isMainBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/Main')] 
  isMinorBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/Minor/')]
  isHotfixBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/Hotfix/')] 

name: $(version.MajorMinor).$(version.Revision)  

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set the minorVersionNumber and hotfixNumber variable values
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [string] $dateTime = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss')
      [string] $minorVersionNumber = "$(stableVersionNumber)-ci$dateTime+$(Build.SourceVersion)"
      [string] $hotFixVersionNumber = "$(version.MajorMinor).$(version.Revision).$(version.HotFix)"
      Write-Host "Setting the prerelease version number variable to '$minorVersionNumber'."
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minorVersionNumber]$minorVersionNumber"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set the versionNumber
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [boolean] $isMain = $$(isMainBranch)
      [boolean] $isMinor = $$(isMinorBranch) 
      [string] $versionNumber = "$(minorVersionNumber)"
      if ($isMain)
      {
        $versionNumber = "$(stableVersionNumber)"
      }
      elseif ($isMinor)
      {
        $versionNumber = "$(minorVersionNumber)"
      }
      else {
        $versionNumber = "$(hotFixVersionNumber)"
      }
      Write-Host "Setting the version number to use to '$versionNumber'."
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionNumber]$versionNumber"
      git config user.email ${{variables['user.email']}}
      git config user.name ${{variables['user.name']}}
      git tag "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      git push origin "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
    displayName: 'git tag'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['isMainBranch'])
```

When merging a "Major" and "Hotfix" the pipeline works perfectly, only when merging a "Minor" the pipeline continues and sees it as a "Hotfix" (this is because it passes the if statement and comes out on the else statement "hotfix").

Where is it going wrong in this pipeline that "minor" is not merged with tagnumber x.1.x

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that these variables are not working as intended:

```
isMinorBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/Minor/')]
isHotfixBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/Hotfix/')]
```

The check in `isMainBranch` doesn't have a trailing slash, so why do these? In result, `isMinorBranch` and `isHotfixBranch` are always false and the script falls into the last `else` statement.

To prove that hypotesis, try echoing variable values in your script, i.e.:

```
write-host 'sourcebranch=${{variables['Build.SourceBranch']}}'
write-host 'isMinorBranch=$(isMinorBranch)'
write-host 'isHotfixBranch=$(isHotfixBranch)'
```

You can also change the last `else` to:

```
elseif ($isHotfix) {
    $versionNumber = "$(hotFixVersionNumber)"
}
else {
    throw "not main, not minor, not hotfix. What is it?"
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution and the missing trailing backslash was indeed missing. However the boolean expressions still came out False and the sourcebranch (Build.SourceBranch) and Build.SourceBranchName come out as refs/heads/main. Not the intended pullrequest from Major/Branchname which should resolve to sourcebranch being Major/Branchname.
 
I also tried ${{variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranchName']}} and that comes out blank after merging the pullrequest.

Comment: Am I using the wrong variables here? Because it seems like the source and targetbranch somehow get mixed up.
 
When configuring the pipeline to use the PullRequest trigger and then creating the branch in the GUI it picks up the sourcebranch as intended. However after completing the pullrequest it seems like it mixes up source and targetbranch and defaults to sourcebranch always being refs/heads/main

Comment: That makes sense. `Build.SourceBranch` is the name of the branch that triggered the build. When you manually chose a branch in GUI, it will be that branch. When you configure a branch policy for PRs, this will be PR branch. But when it runs because of `trigger: main`, it will be `main`. 
I don' think there's a builtin way of determining the name of the branch that was just merged into master when running that build. Maybe parsing the last commit message would be an option?